# how to disable spring boot logo in stdout?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback

Is there a way to disable the lovely but very visible ASCII Spring boot logo :

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.1.8.RELEASE)
```

...dumped in STDOUT every time your run a spring boot app?

I switched all logging to ERROR in my logback.xml, but that did nothing:

```
<root level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

**edit: It's not called a "Logo" in the documentation. The search-friendly-term is a "banner".**

Comment: Add `spring.main.show_banner=false` to your application.properties.

Comment: it's said that "spring.main.show_banner=false" has been deprecated

Answer (score 162, accepted):

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-banner

```
new SpringApplicationBuilder()
    .showBanner(false)
    .sources(Parent.class)
    .child(Application.class)
    .run(args);
```

**Edit**
In the newer versions of spring boot(current is 1.3.3) the way to do it is:

1) application.properties

`spring.main.banner-mode=off`

2) application.yml

```
spring:
    main:
        banner-mode: "off"
```

3) main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(MySpringConfiguration.class);
    app.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
    app.run(args);
}
```

[Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-banner)

Edit:

To change this with and environment variable use the property with underscore instead of dot. Try:

SPRING_MAIN_BANNER-MODE=off

See the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) for externalized config.

Comment: Perfect. I was frantically googling the docs about a "logo", but it's called a banner. Well, thank you !

Comment: It's good though -now all of us searching for logo find this page (;

Comment: should be `new SpringApplicationBuilder().bannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF)` as showBanner is now deprecated

Comment: What's the environment variable equivalent of this? I don't have access to the spring boot app directly (it's a docker image) and so i am setting spring properties via env vars.

Comment: For an environment variable, I would recommend "SPRING_MAIN_BANNER_MODE", with an underscore instead of a "-", in case the server doesn't support dashes in environment variables.

Answer (score 30):

Another option is adding custom banner in a *banner.txt* file to your classpath, that will change to your custom banner.

1. create a file *banner.txt* in the classpath (i.e: *src/main/resources*)
2. Edit you custom banner
3. Run the application

Comment: And if doing this, these tools might be useful: https://www.google.ca/search?q=ascii+text+generator

Answer (score 16):

This has changed slightly in Spring Boot 1.3. The property is now:

```
spring.main.banner_mode=off
```

In code, it is now:

```
springApplication.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
```

or using the builder:

```
new SpringApplicationBuilder()
.bannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can set `spring.main.show_banner=false` in your `application.properties` as described in http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html.

Answer (score 8):

To remove this:

1)   `spring.main.banner-mode=off`

Add above line in the file

```
application.properties
```

OR

2) USE this in Main java class

```
setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
```

OR

3) in-app*.yml file

```
spring:
        main :
               banner-mode=off
```

User This Link for More Details

http://mytechnologythought.blogspot.com/2017/07/how-to-remove-spring-boot-banner.html

Comment: shloud be quote or single quote

`banner-mode='off'`
`banner-mode="off"`

Comment: please do not use single or double . use Just plain off

Comment: You are right, basically. But some old version (eg. 2.1.6.RELEASE) Spring Boot had BindException problem.

`Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Boolean] to type [org.springframework.boot.Banner$Mode]
 at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:321) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]`

Comment: cool I am glad :)

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Spring Boot 1.3 and application.yml (not properties) then you need to quote the 'OFF' i.e.

```
spring:
  main:
    banner_mode: 'OFF'
```

Answer (score 2):

create a file "application.yml" under src/main/resources"
and paste the below code.That would do the job

```
spring:
    main:
        banner-mode: "off"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to remove banner

```
import org.springframework.boot.Banner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication


public class SpringBootConsoleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(SpringBootConsoleApplication.class);
        app.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
        app.run(args);

    }

}
```