# Spring Boot 2 application.properties in war-deployment on wildfly 14

Tags: spring-boot, wildfly

I have a small **spring boot** project which should be deployed on a **wildfly 14**. With spring boot 1 all went well, but after migration to spring boot 2 my settings in application.properties are not used.

I have set `spring.main.banner-mode="off"` but when the war is deployed it shows the banner in console. When starting the project standalone the banner is hidden.

My application class looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

}
```

And my application.properties is right under `src/main/resources`.

Does anyone had the same problem or could gibe me an advice how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi is "off" a typing error ?
Please try:

```
spring.main.banner-mode=off
```

Comment: i tried it both ways. It did not change the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
app.setBannerMode(Mode.OFF);
app.run(args);
```

Related question : [how to disable spring boot logo in stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26585959/how-to-disable-spring-boot-logo-in-stdout)

Comment: I think this is not such a good solution. It is static and i am afraid that no property of the application.properties is affected in my scenario.